# Spring Application loads twice

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm new to Spring and trying to get a example to work. But my application loads twice each time it starts. I think it could be a context problem because of my internet research and I have just one context.xml.

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

     <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:environment.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:environment.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false"/>
    </bean>

    <bean name="objectMapper" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper" />

   <bean name="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
      <property name="requestFactory" ref="requestFactory" />
   </bean>

   <bean name="requestFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory">
      <property name="connectTimeout" value="10000" />
      <property name="readTimeout" value="10000" />
   </bean>

   <bean name="httpClient" class="org.apache.http.client.HttpClient" factory-bean="requestFactory" factory-method="getHttpClient"/>

    <bean name="TraderApplication" class="net.mrmoor.TraderApplication"/>

    <bean name="API" class="com.iggroup.api.API"/>
    <bean name="LightStreamerComponent" class="com.iggroup.api.streaming.LightStreamerComponent"/>

</beans>
```

My code of the TraderApplication Class is:

```
... skipped imports ....

@SpringBootApplication
public class TraderApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TraderApplication.class);

@Autowired
protected ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@Autowired
private API api;

@Autowired
private LightStreamerComponent lightStreamerComponent = new LightStreamerComponent();

private AuthenticationResponseAndConversationContext authenticationContext = null;
private ArrayList<HandyTableListenerAdapter> listeners = new ArrayList<HandyTableListenerAdapter>();

public static void main(String args[]) {
    SpringApplication.run(TraderApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    try {
        if (args.length < 2) {
            log.error("Usage:- Application identifier password apikey");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        String identifier = args[0];
        String password = args[1];
        String apiKey = args[2];
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/public-api-client-spring-context.xml");
        TraderApplication app = (TraderApplication) applicationContext.getBean("TraderApplication");
        app.run(identifier, password, apiKey);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Unexpected error:", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside `run()` and examine the full stack trace

Comment: You are starting your class twice. Once by running the main method and then again you create on by loading another context which again creates a `net.mrmoor.TraderApplication`. Why are you even constructing a context yourself, that basically beats the whole purpose of using spring boot.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I copied the context file to get it to work :( But with your hint I managed to get the problem solved by changing my code to: `this.run(identifier, password, apiKey);` and removing the rest ;)

Comment: FYI you have org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer defined twice.

Comment: I had the same problem about the Spring Boot application starting twice.
My mistake was that I had annotated the main class with `@ComponentScan("...")` and `@SpringBootApplication`.

However, `ComponentScan` is already contained in `SpringBootApplication`. Thus, it was executed twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention in your comments above you got this working by removing SpringApplication.run(TraderApplication.class, args); but this would be removing spring-boot from your application so I'm going to assume since your question has a tag of [spring-boot] that this is not what you wanted. So here is an alternative way that you can configure beans using your xml.

```
@ImportResource({"classpath*:public-api-client-spring-context.xml"}) //Proper way to import xml in Spring Boot
@SpringBootApplication
public class TraderApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    ...code you had before goes here 

    @Autowired
    TraderApplication app;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        .. your parsing logic here

        app.run(identifier, password, apiKey); //Now uses the autowired instance

    }
}
```

You didn't list your pom.xml or build.gradle but it's important to remember that components you have registered in your context xml may be automatically configured in Spring Boot and you may not need to register them yourself in your xml.(Depending on which items you have starters for in your build file)